# Modifying django admin site to accommodate mongodb

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-admin, mongoengine

I have read some posts such as
[Django admin site with mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552938/django-admin-site-with-mongodb)
. However, most posts are extremely outdated (like using django 1.3) and links fail to open. So I decided to repost.
I am using django 1.8 and I am trying to make the django admin site display my collections in mongodb just as it would for relational databases. I use mongoengine for ORM so I have classes in models.py to correspond to mongo collections. My mongo collections all have a predefined structure and doesn't contain Listfields that would confuse the django admin site. How should I go about modifying the django admin site to make it accommodate mongodb?